# Mule 3.2 XSLT node: How to keep the original payload as well as the transformed payload?

Tags: transform, mule

I am trying to create a mule flow (still on mule 3.2). My flow has to take an inbound message, transform the message using an xslt node and then send the transformed message to a destination. The problem I have is, the destination type and the destination where I am supposed to send my transformed message are in the original message. But after the transformation, I do not have access to the original message anymore.

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

Any help will be appreciated!!!

thanks!!!

Comment: Just so I said it: really consider upgrading to 3.3, many bugs have been fixed and the new expression language is available in this release.

Answer (score 0):

Store the original message in a flow variable (aka an invocation-scoped message property). You can retrieve it from there after the transformation.